# MVVM - Does validation really have to be so cumbersome?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

In my application I have tons of forms, most of with having there own models which they bind to! Of course data validation is important, but is there not a better solution than implementing IDataErrorInfo for all of your models and then writing code for all of the properties to validate them?

I have created validation helpers which remove alot of the actual validation code, but still I can't help but feel I am missing a trick or two! Might I add that this is the first application which I have used MVVM within so I am sure I have alot to learn on this subject!

EDIT:

This is the code from a typical model that I really don't like (let me explain):

```
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValidationError(propertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Validation

    string GetValidationError(String propertyName)
    {
        string error = null;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "carer_title":
                error = ValidateCarerTitle();
                break;
            case "carer_forenames":
                error = ValidateCarerForenames();
                break;
            case "carer_surname":
                error = ValidateCarerSurname();
                break;
            case "carer_mobile_phone":
                error = ValidateCarerMobile();
                break;
            case "carer_email":
                error = ValidateCarerEmail();
                break;
            case "partner_title":
                error = ValidatePartnerTitle();
                break;
            case "partner_forenames":
                error = ValidatePartnerForenames();
                break;
            case "partner_surname":
                error = ValidatePartnerSurname();
                break;
            case "partner_mobile_phone":
                error = ValidatePartnerMobile();
                break;
            case "partner_email":
                error = ValidatePartnerEmail();
                break;
        }

        return error;
    }

    private string ValidateCarerTitle()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(carer_title))
        {
            return "Please enter the carer's title";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersOnly(carer_title))
                return "Only letters are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidateCarerForenames()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(carer_forenames))
        {
            return "Please enter the carer's forename(s)";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersSpacesHyphensOnly(carer_forenames))
                return "Only letters, spaces and dashes are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidateCarerSurname()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(carer_surname))
        {
            return "Please enter the carer's surname";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersSpacesHyphensOnly(carer_surname))
                return "Only letters, spaces and dashes are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidateCarerMobile()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(carer_mobile_phone))
        {
            return "Please enter a valid mobile number";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isNumericWithSpaces(carer_mobile_phone))
                return "Only numbers and spaces are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidateCarerEmail()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(carer_email))
        {
            return "Please enter a valid email address";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isEmailAddress(carer_email))
                return "The email address entered is not valid";
        }
        return null;
    }

    private string ValidatePartnerTitle()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(partner_title))
        {
            return "Please enter the partner's title";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersOnly(partner_title))
                return "Only letters are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidatePartnerForenames()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(partner_forenames))
        {
            return "Please enter the partner's forename(s)";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersSpacesHyphensOnly(partner_forenames))
                return "Only letters, spaces and dashes are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidatePartnerSurname()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(partner_surname))
        {
            return "Please enter the partner's surname";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isLettersSpacesHyphensOnly(partner_surname))
                return "Only letters, spaces and dashes are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidatePartnerMobile()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(partner_mobile_phone))
        {
            return "Please enter a valid mobile number";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isNumericWithSpaces(partner_mobile_phone))
                return "Only numbers and spaces are valid";
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string ValidatePartnerEmail()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partner_email))
        {
            return "Please enter a valid email address";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ValidationHelpers.isEmailAddress(partner_email))
                return "The email address entered is not valid";
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
```

The idea of having a switch statement to identify the correct property and then having to write unique validation functions for each property just feels too much (not in terms of work to do, but in terms of the amount of code required). Maybe this is an elegant solution, but it just doesn't feel like one!

Note: I will be converting my validation helpers into extensions as recommended in one of the answers (thanks Sheridan)

SOLUTION:

So, following the answer which I have accepted this is the bare bones of what I implemented to get it working initially (obviously I will be improving parts - but I just wanted to get it going first as I had little experience using lambda expressions or reflection prior to implementing this).

Validtion Dictionary class (showing the main functions):

```
    private Dictionary<string, _propertyValidators> _validators;
    private delegate string _propertyValidators(Type valueType, object propertyValue);


    public ValidationDictionary()
    {
        _validators = new Dictionary<string, _propertyValidators>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(Expression<Func<string>> property, params Func<T, string>[] args)
    {
        // Acquire the name of the property (which will be used as the key)
        string propertyName = ((MemberExpression)(property.Body)).Member.Name;

        _propertyValidators propertyValidators = (valueType, propertyValue) =>
        {
            string error = null;
            T value = (T)propertyValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < args.Count() && error == null; i++)
            {
                error = args[i].Invoke(value);
            }

            return error;
        };

        _validators.Add(propertyName, propertyValidators);
    }

    public Delegate GetValidator(string Key)
    {
        _propertyValidators propertyValidator = null;
        _validators.TryGetValue(Key, out propertyValidator);
        return propertyValidator;
    }
```

Model implementation:

```
public FosterCarerModel()
    {
        _validationDictionary = new ValidationDictionary();
        _validationDictionary.Add<string>( () => carer_title, IsRequired);
    }

    public string IsRequired(string value)
    { 
        string error = null;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            error = "Validation Dictionary Is Working";
        }

        return error;
    }
```

IDataErrorInfo implementation (which is part of the model implementation):

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            Delegate temp = _validationDictionary.GetValidator(propertyName);

            if (temp != null)
            {
                string propertyValue = (string)this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
                return (string)temp.DynamicInvoke(typeof(string), propertyValue);
            }                

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Ignore my slapdash naming conventions and in places coding, I am just so pleased to have got this working! A special thanks to nmclean of course, but also thanks to everyone that contributed to this question, all of the replies were extremely helpful but after some consideration I decided to go with this approach!

Comment: For shared objects, can you not move the validation attributes into an interface so save some of the repetition?

Comment: Another option is to validate by exception but of course this has other limitations. What exactly do you find cumbersome? I think IDataErrorInfo is quiet elegant in that matter. With some helper classes of course, some custom Attributes with validation strategies come to my mind.

Comment: I suppose showing how the `IDataErrorInfo` can be implemented to work with a type of 'error/validation factory/helper' class would be good.

Comment: couldn't data annotations take away a bit of the work?  http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/04/27/wpf-data-validation-using-dataannotations/

Comment: @mattytommo - there aren't so many shared objects as such, I did consider your approach but I feel it wouldn't help the situation all that much, and if anything make things even "messier" - thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @dowhilefor - the whole idea of writing a switch statement to run through all of the property names, then calling a specific function for that property, having to write functions to validate each and every single property! Don't get me wrong I may be going about it all completely wrong... but isn't this approach excessive?

Comment: You could implement a strategy factory depending on the complexity of your validation proceedures. However, this may well be overkill...

Comment: @Killercam - I am not familiar with validation strategies, what does this ential?

Comment: @Sam thats what i mean a proper implementation would take away the need of writing a "switch" statement, in fact you would just use attributes to say "for this one use this validation strategy" there is no need for attributes though, i just like them.

Comment: I just mean instead of a `switch`/`case` stamen to determine the validation method, use a strategy/factory pattern...

Comment: @Killercam - could you possibly post a link of any articles/tutorials/help regarding strategy/factory patterns which might help me in understanding this approach?

Comment: @dowhilefor - ahhh I see, that seems to be exactly what I need! As asked above, could you possibly post a link of any articles/tutorials/help regarding strategy/factory patterns which might help me in understanding this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine looks something like this:

```
new ValidationDictionary() {
    {() => carer_title,
        ValidationHelpers.Required(() => "Please enter the carer's title"),
        ValidationHelpers.LettersOnly(() => "Only letters are valid")}
}
```

ValidationDictionary is a dictionary of string -> delegate. It overloads `Add` to accept a lambda expression which is converted to a property name string for the key, and a `params` array of delegates that are consolidated into one delegate for the value. The delegates accept some information like the property type and value, and return an error message or `null`.

In this case, `Required` and `LettersOnly` are higher-order functions which generate delegates that return the given strings when invalid. The strings themselves are passed in as delegates so they can be dynamic.

IDataErrorInfo is implemented by simply looking up the property name in the dictionary and calling the delegate to get an error message.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am extremely intrigued by your answer however I have a few questions. 1) how come you pass the key as a lambda expression and not as a string i.e. "carer_title". Is it so you can resolve the property at runtime? If so, why? Secondly, how come you pass the error message to your validators as lambda expressions (I know you said so they can be dynamic, but I can't get my head around what is going on)? Don't get mad at me, I have never used lambda expressions creatively (like your solution) and I really like your way of doing this but am struggling to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Just to expand on my confusion, normally Validation.Required would take the properties text as the value right, well, how would it if it is taking the error message as the parameter (and again, why as a lambda expression and not as a string)?! Note: I am not questioning you or your solution, but just how it all works... any extra code would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again for your time

Comment: Update - so I am fine with why you implement carer_title as a lambda expression opposed to as a string - so that if you rename properties you don't have to worry about renaming all of the strings as well etc. (right?)

Comment: @Sam 1) Yes, it ensures that the strings will always be "in sync" with the actual properties. It's also nice that the IDE can suggest the properties as I type instead of me manually typing them as a string.

Comment: @Sam 2) Suppose you want to include the current value of the property (or even a different property) within the error text, so you use `String.Format("the value {0} is not valid", this.carer_title)`. If you passed that in directly, it would always show the value it had when the dictionary was created. By using a delegate (which is called each time), you will always see the *current* value. This could also look up a string based on the current language so your application could support switching languages on the fly.

Comment: @Sam 3) `Required` isn't the delegate that gets called for validation -- it *generates* the delegate to use, i.e. it's a function that returns a function (a higher-order function). That line would be equivalent to something like `value => { if (value == null) return "Please enter the carer's title"; else return null; }` Here's an example of how you might implement `Required`: http://ideone.com/7hRRIL

Comment: Soooooo, I just finished implementing this, and it works perfectly! Although, I didn't add the dynamic error messages like you have as I didn't get how that would work! I would still appreciate it if you could explain that to me please :). Thanks again (I will post my code for any future MVVM newbies - to save them from the mess I got into!)

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I see (sorry I hadn't refreshed to see your replies) - you have literally helped me so much! This was exactly the sort of solution I was looking for (without knowing it lol). And, I get what you mean now regarding validation helpers - that's a nice way of implementing it actually! Thanks again for the support

Answer (score 6):

I use `extension` methods to reduce the amount of validation text that I have to write. If you are unfamiliar with them, please take a look at the [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) page at MSDN to find out about `extension` methods. I have dozens of these that validate every situation. As an example:

```
if (propertyName == "Title" && !Title.ValidateMaximumLength(255)) error = 
    propertyName.GetMaximumLengthError(255);
```

In the `Validation.cs` class:

```
public static bool ValidateMaximumLength(this string input, int characterCount)
{
    return input.IsNullOrEmpty() ? true : input.Length <= characterCount;
}

public static string GetMaximumLengthError(this string input, int characterCount, 
    bool isInputAdjusted)
{
    if (isInputAdjusted) return input.GetMaximumLengthError(characterCount);
    string error = "The {0} field requires a value with a maximum of {1} in it.";
    return string.Format(error, input, characterCount.Pluralize("character"));
}
```

Note that `Pluralize` is another `extension` method that simply adds an "s" to the end of the input parameter if the input value does not equal 1. Another method might be:

```
public static bool ValidateValueBetween(this int input, int minimumValue, int 
    maximumValue)
{
    return input >= minimumValue && input <= maximumValue;
}

public static string GetValueBetweenError(this string input, int minimumValue, int 
    maximumValue)
{
    string error = "The {0} field value must be between {1} and {2}.";
    return string.Format(error, input.ToSpacedString().ToLower(), minimumValue, 
        maximumValue);
}
```

Of course, it will take a while to implement all the methods that you will require, but then you'll save plenty of time later and you will have the added benefit of all of your error messages being consistent.

Comment: I like this approach. Well played.

Comment: This is very similar to what I am doing, however I have not implemented them as extensions - I definitely will be doing this now though! I am going to update my question with some code that I really hate and would like to reduce. Thanks

Comment: That pluralize extension is horrific. How do you handle localisation? Is it gender aware, tense aware?

Comment: @Gusdor the application is clearly not localised if he is hard coding strings. It is an illustration...

Comment: Something more constructive - an accepted solution(s) is providing a string with optional pluralisation(s) as demonstrated. It wont be perfect, but it is a nice placeholder until you decide to be more precise.

Comment: @Killercam Your codebase should allow the consumer to walk the edge of the pit of success, not the pit of failure. This extension method can easily cause hard-to-notice errors and is best avoided.

Comment: @Gusdor, it's a simple `extension` method with overloads that handle changing singular words to plural dependant on a number. It's not meant to be an all singing, all dancing function... it just means that my applications will *never* display something like '1 items' or '6 item' and that's more than I can say for many other applications. It's always worked well for me, but if you don't like the idea, simply don't implement it. Also, the `Pluralise` method has nothing to do with this answer, so I really don't understand why you're making such a big deal about nothing again.

Comment: @Gusdor Implying that code is wrong if it does not account for localisation or edge cases regarding string labels is over-engineering and a violation of YAGNI. There might be specific requirements in the app that say this is OK for the moment. Its fine to make a point about the lack of localisation, but to harp on it just makes you look cranky.

Comment: @Graham this whole thing makes the rest of you look lazy. Arguably, ensuring your strings are in resource files is just good mvvm. Separation of concerns and all that.

Comment: @Sheridan i raised it because some junior programmer will come alone and yoink the concept without thinking it though, assuming brighter people had and might run into the problem down the line, AFTER their company has paid the translator. It is ours to educate when using this platform.

Comment: @Gusdor - the fact that you think the company NEEDS a translator clearly demonstrates that you are thinking in terms where localisation matters. That's fine, FOR YOU. Not all companies in the world care about supporting multiple languages (I've personally never worked for one that cared). Again, you are projecting your requirements into this problem. If a junior programmer who works for a firm that needs localisation sees this answer, they will soon discover how to modify it as such. Not every SO answer needs to account for every possible requirement.

Comment: @Graham I never claimed the answer was bad, just that that particular portion has associated issues. I tell you what, next time i write the code for a console app in an answer, I will put Process.Kill(); at the end of Main() and make pariahs out of anyone who dares point it out.

Comment: That's a nice over-reaction @Gusdor. Either way, can we *please* just drop all this nonsense now, as it adds absolutely nothing to this question or answer?

Answer (score 5):

I personally like the FluentValidation approach.

This replaces your switch table with expression based rules like:

```
            RuleFor(x => x.Username)
                .Length(3, 8)
                .WithMessage("Must be between 3-8 characters.");

            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .Matches(@"^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$")
                .WithMessage("Must contain lower, upper and numeric chars.");

            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .EmailAddress()
                .WithMessage("A valid email address is required.");

            RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
                .Must(BeAValidDateOfBirth)
                .WithMessage("Must be within 100 years of today.");
```

from http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/silverlight-5-validation.html

There's more information on this http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ - although the docs there are mainly web-MVC based. For Wpf, there are also a few blog posts around like http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/fluent-validation-wpf-implementation.html

Answer (score 4):

You're right.  A switch statement is too much.  It's much easier to isolate IDEI (and INotifyDataErrorInfo) logic into a base class.

A simple way to accomplish this is to expose a method to set an error on a property, and to clear a property's error.  This would be simple to implement, although you would have to code the validation for each property.

```
public string SomeProperty { get { return _someProperty; }
    set
    {
        _someProperty = value;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            SetError("SomeProperty", "You must enter a value or something kthx");
        else
            ClearError("SomeProperty");
    }
```

Where, in the base class, you keep a Dictionary that simply holds these error values

```
protected void SetError(string propertyName, string error)
{
    _errors[propertyName] = error;
{
```

and delivers them on demand, e.g.,

```
string IDataErrorInfo.Error
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _errors.Values);
    }
}
```

This kind of pattern can become more powerful when you combine it with Data annotations, a little reflection, and some features from 4.5 to avoid validation completely.

There are several examples of using the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) to [simply and cleanly implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a base class](http://refactorthis.net/post/2012/11/08/C-50-INotifyPropertyChanged-with-the-CallerMemberName-attribute.aspx).  If you have the name of the property being set, and use reflection (cache it after the first call if you're worried about perf) to get any data annotations on the property, you can perform all your validation checks and store the results all within the base class.  That would simplify your derived class' properties to something like the following:

```
[NotNullOrWhiteSpace, NotADirtyWord, NotViagraSpam]
public string SomeProperty{ 
    get {return _lol;} 
    set{ _lol = value; PropertyChanged(); } }
```

Which radically simplifies the whole validation pipeline for only a small amount of work.